# Persistent header layout in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-xml

I have a ViewPager that can slide to 3 different pages. All 3 of the pages should have the exact same header.

Is there a way to keep the same header across all 3 pages so that when I slide to another page, the header doesn't move/change but the rest of the content does?

Here is my ViewPager layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the header layout I load above the ViewPager:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="User"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is how I inflate the header:

```
final ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, listView, false);
listView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the header outside of the view pager. Use layout_weight for the viewpager so that it takes the entire available space.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="User"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How would I set it as a header like I do in my code? Otherwise, the layout isn't scrollable, only the ViewPager would be.

Comment: The above layout includes both the header and the viewpager. What do you mean by 'layout is not scrollable'?

Comment: A ListView is a scrollable layout. How I have it set up now, I use `addHeaderView()` to add the layout as a header to the ListView. If I do what you said, only the ViewPager is scrollable (a small portion of the screen) while the header layout stays on the screen all the time, even when I scroll.

Comment: I am confused. In the first part of the question you said that you want to display header which is common to pages being swiped. In the second part, you are saying you want to add some header to listview. My answer is only to the first part.

Comment: Yes, I originally have the header apart of a ListView, but I also have a ViewPager.